# Where can I find lore about the Shadow of Ao?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, artifacts

So I was perusing the wiki when I stumbled upon this:

> The Shadow of Ao was a powerful artifact said to have been lost after the sundering of Abeir-Toril.   Abilities:
> Legend had that the Shadow of Ao had the power to split the world in two.

This seems like its a pretty major artifact! So are there any lore or stats for it? Thank you in advance.

Any edition is fine i'm just curious because nothing really turned up when I looked for it.
Link:https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Shadow_of_Ao

Comment: If destroying a world is one's objective, it's usually safer to [nuke it from orbit, as it is the only way to be sure ...](https://youtu.be/DHFvhAiAsoU) 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The wiki already has all the information

I looked it up in the source material (namely the [Forgotten Realms Campaign Guide](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Campaign_Guide)) and the only mention of the item is seen below

[image: Forgotten Realms Campaign Guide, p.210]

Unfortunately there is no description and it gets only mentioned once. Furthermore the "Ao" from the item is a powerful god, so it is likely that a very powerful item with a description of "twin the world anew" named after him has no concrete stats.

There is more lore for Ao available [here](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ao).

Comment: It talks about Melabrauth sending his servants to look for it under the history tab for the 
Shadow of Ao, but this seems to confirm that no other official lore exists.